# looking for a regular expression to extract all text outputs to user from js file

Tags: regex

i have some huge js files and there are some texts/messages/... which are output for a human beeing. the problem is they don't run over the same method.

but i want to find them all to refactor the code.
now i am searching for a regular expression to find those messages.

```
...his.submit_register = function(){
        if(!this.agb_accept.checked) {
            out_message("This is a Messge tot the User in English." , "And the Title of the Box. In English as well");
            return fals;
        }
        this.valida...
```

what i want to find is all the strings which are not source code.
in this case i want as return:

- This is a Messge tot the User in
- English. And the Title of the Box. In
  English as well

i tried something like: `/\"(\S+\s{1})+\S\"/`, but this wont work ...

thanks for help

Comment: How are you planning to identify strings containing English from strings which don't contain English? There is no regular expression that matches English text. Are you happy for this to be a manual process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to parse Javascript source code using regular expressions because Javascript is not a regular language. You can write a regular expression that works most of the time:

```
/"(.*?)"/
```

The `?` means that the match is not greedy.

Note: this will not correctly handle strings that contain ecaped quotes.

Comment: it finds all but more. so for my purpose it is enough. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A simple java regex solving your problem (assuming that the message doesn't contain a " character):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(.+?)\"");
```

The extraction code :

```
Matcher m;

for(String line : lines) {
    m = p.matcher(line);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```